# Best practice/conventions to reduce large number of method arguments

Tags: php

I have a method as follows:

```
public function updateContact(Contact $contact,
      string $accountNumber = null,
      string $contactStatus = 'ACTIVE',
      string $name = null,
      string $primaryPersonFirstName = null,
      string $primaryPersonLastName = null,
      string $primaryPersonEmail = null,
      string $defaultCurrency = null,
      string $taxNumber = null,
      string $postalAddress1 = null,
      string $postalAddress2 = null,
      string $postalCity = null,
      string $postalRegion = null,
      string $postalPostalCode = null,
      string $postalCountryName = null,
      string $streetAddress1 = null,
      string $streetAddress2 = null,
      string $streetCity = null,
      string $streetRegion = null,
      string $streetPostalCode = null,
      string $streetCountryName = null
) {
```

These are only some of the possible arguments to complete all functions. What are peoples thoughts on ways to reduce the argument list. I see a few options:

- Take a single array. Disadvantage here is the user needs to know what goes into the array where as in the argument list it is more obvious.
- Methods for each update opteration i.e. `public function updateAccountNumber($account_number)`. The disadvantage here being the sheer number of methods required.

What is the general convention for things like this?

Comment: I would pass an array as an argument containing all those values. Or create an address class with getters and setters and pass that as an argument

Comment: Questions regarding code quality and best practices should be directed to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). That being said, the common approach is to pass an associative array of values so that you don't have to memorize parameter order.

Comment: one idea `function update($field,$value){//should be obvious what goes here}` then call `update('accountNumber', $accountNumber)`, you could get fancy and allow multiple fields

Comment: *"Disadvantage here is the user needs to know what goes into the array"*, Who is the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Take a single array. Disadvantage here is the user needs to know what goes into the array where as in the argument list it is more obvious.

Just like you suggested, I'd pass a single array of options, maybe through the class constructor?

However, to tackle what you say about "user needs to know what goes into the array", I'd consider creating some sort of function to set the options.

**Basic Example:**

```
class Example {

  private $options = array();

  public function setOption($option, $value) {
    $this->options[$option] = $value;
  }

}
```

or, if you specific only want certain options set, something like this:

**Example Two:**

```
class Example {

  private $options = array();
  private $acceptedOptions = array('accountNumber','contactStatus','name','and_so_on...');

  public function setOption($option, $value) {
    if (!in_array($option, $this->acceptedOptions)) return false;
    $this->options[$option] = $value;
    return $this->options;
  }

}
```

That way, you can now set options for you class like this:

```
$myClass = new Example;
$myClass->setOption('name', 'Jonathan');
```

And you can see if it was accepted too, like this:

```
$myClass = new Example;
$accepted = $myClass->setOption('name', 'Jonathan');
if (!$accepted) {
   // Yikes it didn't work.
}
```